# Difference between NUMBER & NUMBER(16) in oracle?

Tags: oracle, numbers, sqldatatypes

In current database I have column with NUBMER(16) however due to transaction size ncreased to 17 char I am planning to make it NUMBER which supports 32 char numeric.

As size and performance wise I want to know how it would impact to database?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/tablecls.htm#CNCPT313),

> Oracle Database stores numeric data in **variable-length format**. Each
>   value is stored in scientific notation, with 1 byte used to store the
>   exponent. The database uses up to 20 bytes to store the mantissa,
>   which is the part of a floating-point number that contains its
>   significant digits. Oracle Database does not store leading and
>   trailing zeros.

Therefore, the **storage** would depend on the **actual numeric value** and not just the **precision**.

> Precision is the number of significant digits.

To see the storage, use `vsize` and `dump`.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t (val NUMBER(16));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES (-12);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES (1);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES (12);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES (1234);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES (12345);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES (123456789012345);

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.
```

Let's check the size:

```
SQL> SELECT val, vsize(val), dump(val) FROM t ORDER BY val DESC;

             VAL       VSIZE(VAL) DUMP(VAL)
---------------- ---------------- --------------------------------------
 123456789012345                9 Typ=2 Len=9: 200,2,24,46,68,90,2,24,46
           12345                4 Typ=2 Len=4: 195,2,24,46
            1234                3 Typ=2 Len=3: 194,13,35
              12                2 Typ=2 Len=2: 193,13
               1                2 Typ=2 Len=2: 193,2
             -12                3 Typ=2 Len=3: 62,89,102

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit for you answer. So if i use NUMBER instead of NUMBER(17) it will not take any extra storage if my number is 17 char right ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I said. You can do the compare as I did in the answer.